# PyMC3 estimating size of closed population with time-varying capture probabilities

Tags: python, numpy, theano, bayesian, pymc3

I am trying to port [this example](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/wiki/Mt2) of a latent multinomial model in PyMC2 over to PyMC3.

### Model description

The aim is to estimate the actual number *N* of individuals in a closed population, based on a time series of *T* observation occasions.

There are 2^T possible series for each individual - so if T=2, an individual can either be observed never (0, 0) [let's call this sequence 1], only the first time (1, 0) [sequence 2], only the second time (0, 1) [sequence 3] or both times (1, 1) [sequence 4].

We know if an individual has resulted in sequences 2 to 4, so we have those counts.

However, the model depends on us determining the number of individuals who exist, but were never observed (sequence 1), from sampled values of *N*.

In the original PyMC2 model, this is done by simply appending `N - sum(f)` to the start of `f`, where `f` is an `np.array` of observed counts for sequences 2 to 2^T. In PyMC3 this must be done using Theano, and some of the other variables are also defined as Theano shared variables.

### Original example in PyMC2

The original PyMC2 code looks like this:

```
from pymc import Lambda, Beta, DiscreteUniform, stochastic, multinomial_like
from numpy import reshape, ma, prod, array, append
import pdb

# Constants
T=2
Cells=4
# Observations seen by both observers, just the first observer, or just the second
f=(22,363,174)
# Inidicators for observer sightings
omegas=reshape((0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,1), (Cells, T))

# Capture probabilities
p = Beta('p', alpha=1, beta=1, size=T)

# Cell probabilities
c = Lambda('c', lambda p=p: p**omegas * (1-p)**(1.-omegas))

# Joint probabilities
pi = Lambda('pi', lambda c=c: prod(c, 1))

# Bound total N by the number of observed individuals
N = DiscreteUniform('N', lower=sum(f), upper=10000)

@stochastic(observed=True, dtype=int)
def F(value=f, n=N, p=pi):
    """Complete multinomial for observed and unobserved quatities"""
    return multinomial_like(append(n-sum(value), value), n, p)
```

### Attempted PyMC3 version

My first attempt at a PyMC3 version (in Python 2.7) looks like this:

```
from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function

import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt
from theano import shared

# Constants

T = 2
CELLS = 4

with pm.Model() as model_mt:

    f = shared(np.array((22, 363, 174)))

    omegas = shared(np.reshape((0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,1), (CELLS, T)))

    p = pm.Beta('p', alpha=1, beta=1, shape=T)

    # Treating c and pi as separate steps, as per his example:
    # c = p ** omegas
    # pi = tt.prod(c, axis=1)

    # Shorter line of code:
    pi = tt.prod(p ** omegas, axis=1)

    N = pm.DiscreteUniform('N', lower=f.sum(), upper=10000)

    observed_values = tt.concatenate(([N-tt.sum(f)], f))

    y_obs = pm.Multinomial('y_obs', n=N, p=pi, observed=observed_values)

with model_mt:
    trace = pm.sample(5000)
```

But the resultant trace looks implausible. I get mean values of 0.27 for `p_0` and 0.98 for `p_1`, which I understand to be the values (respectively) for seeing an individual at t=1 and at t=2, while `N` has a mean value of 930. But shouldn't `p_1` be close to `(363+174)/N`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would translate this model to PyMC3 (which I've been meaning to do, so thanks):

```
with pm.Model() as Mt2:

    p = pm.Uniform('p', 0, 1, shape=T)

    c = p**omega * (1 - p)**(1-omega)

    π = pm.Deterministic('π', tt.prod(c, 1))

    π_obs = π[1:] / (1 - π[0])

    f_obs = pm.Potential('f_obs', pm.Multinomial.dist(n=n, p=π_obs).logp(f[1:]))

    N = pm.Uniform('N', 0, 10000)

    n_obs = pm.Potential('n_obs', pm.Binomial.dist(n=tt.floor(N), p=1-π[0]).logp(n))

    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000)
```

Keeping `N` as a continuous variable and using factor potentials for the partially-observed observables allows PyMC3 to use NUTS rather than falling back on Metropolis.

I get an estimate of just over 611 for N:
[image: posterior plot of N]

I can't recall how this compares to the PyMC2 (or Link and Barker) output, but its considerably smaller than your estimate.

Here are my estimates of the capture probabilities:

[image]

I get an estimate of 0.325 (0.290, 0.367) for `p[0]` and 0.894 (0.853, 0.936) for `p[1]`.

Comment: Here's a link to a Jupyter notebook with the model https://gist.github.com/fonnesbeck/1149c6d513ddaef8d71bbed4561088b0